# C# download xml from a github repository

Tags: c#, xml, github, download

I have an XML file that I have uploaded to my GitHub Repository. 
However, I can´t figure out how to download it to my Pc using C#

Anyone can help?

Link to the XML file 
https://github.com/Belchuke/BQuizz-With-Buzzers/blob/master/QuizzQuestions.xml

I have tried this

```
string xml = new WebClient().DownloadString(@"https://github.com/Belchuke/BQuizz-With-Buzzers/blob/master/QuizzQuestions.xml");

XDocument dco = XDocument.Parse(xml);
dco.Save("testXML.xml");
```

How ever this send an exception on line 44

Comment: try using the raw link instead https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Belchuke/BQuizz-With-Buzzers/master/QuizzQuestions.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to **download a file** from a git repository like **Github**, Gitlab, etc you have to use the **raw address** (it will only show the file instead of all the html page).

```
string xml = new WebClient().DownloadString(@"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Belchuke/BQuizz-With-Buzzers/master/QuizzQuestions.xml");
XDocument dco = XDocument.Parse(xml);
dco.Save("testXML.xml");
```

Comment: @Belcookies No problem, validate the answer if it fit your need.

Comment: I will in 5 mins time :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the URL to download the row XML, try this

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Belchuke/BQuizz-With-Buzzers/master/QuizzQuestions.xml

```
string xml = new WebClient().DownloadString(@"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Belchuke/BQuizz-With-Buzzers/master/QuizzQuestions.xml");

        XDocument dco = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        dco.Save("testXML.xml");
```

Comment: This answer doesn't add anything new to this thread since [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57288318/10883465) has the same content.